# Why windows installer executable does not get administrator right when first run in a new machine?

Tags: windows, uac

in my case, I used windows home editon. When I first run a installer exe (it has requireAdministrator attribute)，it runs without administrator privilege( I see some administrator task reports error). If i run it another time, it will has the administrator privilege. Why this could happen?

Comment: The only thing i can think of is your application is freshly-built, and Windows caches the manifest; and is cleared after a reboot (or rename of the file).